# Ошибка Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, yii2

Знания php у меня сырые, решил потренироваться с парсингом данных с сайта с помощью phpQuery остановился в самом начале и уже довольно продолжительное время перебираю варианты.

```
<?php use yii\helpers\Url; ?>

<div class="grid-col grid-col-3 sidebar">
    <!-- widget search -->
    <aside class="widget-search">
        <form method="get" class="search-form" action="<?= Url::to(['/site/blog-search', 'search' => $search])?>">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?=Yii::t('app','Izlash...')?>" value="" name="search" title="Search for:">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="GO">
        </form>
    </aside>
    <!--/ widget search -->
    <!-- widget categories -->
    <aside class="widget-categories">
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <hr class="divider-big" />
        <ul>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat"><a href="#"><?=Yii::t('app','Avtomobil')?></a></li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat"><a href="#"><?=Yii::t('app','Mashinasozlik')?></a></li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat"><a href="#"><?=Yii::t('app','Axborot texnalogiya')?></a></li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat"><a href="#"><?=Yii::t('app','Elektrik')?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <!-- widget categories -->
    <!-- widget recent post -->
    <aside class="widget-post">
        <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
        <div class="carousel-nav">
            <div class="carousel-button">
                <div class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></div><!-- 
             --><div class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="divider-big" />
        <div class="owl-carousel widget-carousel">
            <div>

            <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                <article class="clear-fix">
                    <img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').$user->img?>" data-at2x="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').$user->img?>" alt>
                    <h4><?=$users->title_uz?></h4>
                    <p><?=$user->short_text?></p>
                </article>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <!-- <div>
                <article class="clear-fix">
                    <img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/placeholder.jpg'?>" data-at2x="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/placeholder.jpg'?>" alt>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                    <p>Sed pharetra lorem ut dolor dignissim, sit amet pretium tortor mattis...</p>
                </article>
                <article class="clear-fix">
                    <img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/placeholder.jpg'?>" data-at2x="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/placeholder.jpg'?>" alt>
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                    <p>Sed pharetra lorem ut dolor dignissim, sit amet pretium tortor mattis...</p>
                </article>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- widget recent post -->
    <!-- widget calendar -->
    <aside class="widget-calendar">
        <h2>Calendar</h2>
        <hr class="divider-big" />
        <div id="calendar"></div>
        <hr class="margin-top" />
    </aside>
    <!-- / widget calendar -->
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%20Invalid%20argument%20supplied%20for%20foreach()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%20Invalid%20argument%20supplied%20for%20foreach())

Comment: Попробуйте добавить проверку `<?php if(in_array($users) && isset($users)) { ?> ` `<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>` ...